# Can we declare a class template using fewer parameters than in the template?

Tags: c++, templates

Class template for map is like this

```
template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
       class T,                                       // map::mapped_type
       class Compare = less<Key>,                     // map::key_compare
       class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // map::allocator_type
       > class map;
```

From the template it appears to take 4 template parameters but while declaring a map, I see only two template parameters.

```
map <int, int> table;
```

Is this not a problem? If its not is this correct to just define the type of last two(of the four)?

```
map<,,int,int>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Is this not a problem?

This is not a problem, it's [default template arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments).

> Default template arguments are specified in the parameter lists after the = sign.

It means when you doesn't specify them, such as `map<key_type, value_type>`, the default arguments will be used instead. i.e. `Compare` will be `less<key_type>`, and `Alloc` will be `allocator<pair<const key_type, value_type>>`.

> 2. is this correct to just define the type of last two(of the four)? map<,,int,int>

No. Default arguments are used in place of the missing *trailing* arguments. You can't just specify the last two arguments, without specifying the first two and want the default arguments to be applied. And in this case the first two parameters don't have default argument at all.

BTW

> If the default is specified for a template parameter of a primary class template, each subsequent template parameter must have a default argument, except the very last one may be a template parameter pack.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this not a problem?

No, that's what the default type definitions are for: `= less<Key>` and `= allocator<pair<const Key,T> >`.

As you can see these types can be deduced from `Key` and `T`.

> If its not is this correct to just define the type of last two(of the four)? `map<,,int,int>`

No that can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default parameter for the template.

But only one or more in the end could be the default parameter(i.e. once a default parameter exists, all of the parameters after this parameter must be the default parameter.)

so, your code like this :

`map<,,int,int>`

will be wrong.

the right code like this:

`map<int,int>;`

note: you can refer to *Thinking.In.C++,.Second.Edition.Volume.2*